# error: unexpected token in '.section' directive .section .multiboot

Tags: llvm-clang

I found a sample of simple kernel loader and try to get how it works. But I can't even build it due to errors:

```
loader.s:5:20: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .multiboot
                   ^
loader.s:11:15: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
.section .text
              ^
loader.s:28:1: error: unknown directive
.sectio .bss
```

Here is loader code:

```
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
    .long MAGIC
    .long FLAGS
    .long CHECKSUM


.section .text
.extern main
.extern callConstructors
.global loader

loader:
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    call callConstructors
    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call main

_stop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp _stop

.sectio .bss 
.space 2*1024*1024;
kernel_stack:
```

I compile it as `as -m32 loader.s`.

After search I found that I don't need to use `.section` with `.text` and `.bss` but I don't know what's `.multiboot` section and how to fix this error. I could not find information about `.multiboot` in Google.

**P.S.** If it's important I use MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> P.S. If it's important I use MacOS.

That's part of it. Presumably your `as` is actually the default Apple Clang (LLVM) assembler (check `as --version`) targeting your host machine. This code was written to be built with a [*GCC cross-compiler*](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones#Building_a_Cross-Compiler). The code is assuming you're running under an i686-elf cross compiler specifically. I think LLVM and GCC assemblers are pretty interchangeable, but the directives depend on your output target. For you, `as`/`clang`/whatever on OSX by default assumes you are compiling for your host machine, which I think doesn't use an ELF output target. Passing `-target i686-elf` should do the trick.

That said, if you are pushing forward into more meaty OS/kernel dev, there is [good reason](https://wiki.osdev.org/Why_do_I_need_a_Cross_Compiler%3F) to build yourself a real cross-compiler. Passing a bunch of flags to your host compiler to force it into cross-compiling is probably going to land you in some pain down the road.

EDIT: I found myself to your question because I'm trying to set up an OS dev environment on my Macbook. If you're building a multiboot kernel you will eventually need to link the above snippet with the real kernel, probably using a linker script. Unfortunately I just found out that Apple's `ld` doesn't accept GCC-style linker scripts (real `ld` from LLVM does, so this is an Apple idiosyncrasy), so I'm giving up and just building GCC on my machine. I would recommend that route!

Comment: Thank you for answer, I faced with same problem when tried to pass a linker script.