# Large global array of vectors causing compilation error

Tags: c++

I have a very simple C++ code (it was a large one, but I stripped it to the essentials), but it's failing to compile. I'm providing all the details below.

**The code**

```cpp
#include <vector>
const int SIZE = 43691;
std::vector<int> v[SIZE];

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

**Compilation command:** `g++ -std=c++17 code.cpp -o code`

**Compilation error:**

```
/var/folders/l5/mcv9tnkx66l65t30ypt260r00000gn/T//ccAtIuZq.s:449:29: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
        .section .data.rel.ro.local
                                   ^
```

**GCC version:** `gcc version 12.1.0 (Homebrew GCC 12.1.0_1)`

**Operating system:** `MacOS Monterey, version 12.3, 64bit architecture (M1)`

**My findings and remarks:**

The constant `SIZE` isn't random here. I tried many different values, and `SIZE = 43691` is the first one that causes the compilation error.

My guess is that it is caused by stack overflow. So I tried to compile using the flag `-Wl,-stack_size,0x20000000`, and also tried `ulimit -s 65520`. But neither of them has any effect on the issue, the code still fails to compile once `SIZE` exceeds `43690`.

I also calculated the amount of stack memory this code consumes when `SIZE = 43690`. AFAIK, vectors use `24B` stack memory, so the total comes to `24B * 43690 = 1048560B`. This number is very close to 2<sup>20</sup> = `1048576`. In fact, `SIZE = 43691` is the first time that the consumed stack memory exceeds 2<sup>20</sup>B. Unless this is quite some coincidence, my stack memory is somehow limited to 2<sup>20</sup>B = `2M`. If that really is the case, I still cannot find any way to increase it via the compilation command arguments. All the solutions in the internet leads to the `stack_size` linker argument, but it doesn't seem to work on my machine. I'm wondering now if it's because of the M1 chip somehow.

I'm aware that I can change this code to use vector of vectors to consume memory from the heap, but I have to deal with other's codes very often who are used to coding like this.

Let me know if I need to provide any more details. I've been stuck with this the whole day. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are declaring an array of vectors. You should use `std::vector v(size);`  to create a single vector. Also try to avoid globals if you can.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd suspect the linker is trying to generate a table of constructor functions to be run at startup, one for each `vector`, and runs into some internal limits. The limitation is probably that of the object file format, like the max size of a section. Consider using `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(SIZE);` instead.

Comment: That's a very large static array of vectors. Do you really want an array of vectors, or one vector of said size?

Comment: Static globals are generally stored in the `Data` segment, not on a stack. Data segments are a bit of a blindspot to me, though.

Comment: Suggestion: store a pointer and use dynamic allocation (`new std::vector<int>[SIZE]`).

Comment: Are you cross compiling? You may specify a `-target` that matches your destination architecture? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62630189/2027196

Comment: @PepijnKramer (also Adrian Mole) The code indeed requires an array of vectors (to store the adjacency lists of a graph, which might have up to 10^5 nodes).

Comment: Then why not use : `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` ? And reserve some space up front to avoid reallacations at runtime. That will at least allocate all memory on the heap and bypass the stack completely

Comment: @lorro Thanks for the suggestion. I know that's a viable solution. But as I mentioned, I have to face similar (and complicated) codes very often written by others. So, I really need to figure out a way to make similar codes work in my machine (since it is compiling successfully in their machines, there should be some way).

Comment: What is "it" that you tried and that fails with the same value of `SIZE`?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I actually tried it too. Declaring `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(SIZE);` upfront still fails to compile exactly when `SIZE` exceeds `436910`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, I wasn't clear. I tried changing the array of vectors to a vector of vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(SIZE);`

Comment: use `static constexpr std::size_t SIZE = 43691;`

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't understand. `int`s can hold up to `2^31 = ~10^9` right? But thanks for the suggestion. I tried changing `const int SIZE = 43691;` to `static constexpr std::size_t SIZE = 43691;`. It is also failing unfortunately.

Comment: Are you saying `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(SIZE);` works with `SIZE=100` say, but not with `SIZE=43691`? I find it difficult to believe - the generated code should be almost exactly the same between the two, the only difference being a value passed as an argument to the outer vector's constructor. There must be more to the story.

Comment: It works here : https://godbolt.org/z/GdE8Y1GjM

Comment: What are you compiling with and to what target system? Maybe the target just doesn't have enough memory. I just always use std::size_t when using STL containers (semantics : negative sizes don't make sense. int should indeed be large enough)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am extremely sorry. My bad. I'm a bit confused by the whole issue, so I mistakenly wrote `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v[SIZE];` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(SIZE);` as per your suggestion. You're right, declaring it as a vector of vectors this way works. I guess I'll try it as a temporary solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should not store so many elements on the stack. It's bad design

Comment: Different platforms will have different limits.  Those limits are not "baked" into the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem to be an M1 / M1 Pro issue. I tested your code on two seperate M1 Pro machine with the same result as yours. One workaround I found is to use the x86_64 version of gcc under rosetta, which doesn't have these allocation problems.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and after adding the -O2 flag to the compilation command, it started working. No idea why.

So, something like this:

```
g++-12 -O2 -std=c++17 code.cpp -o code
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on a M1 Max running Monterey 12.5.1 with XCode 13.4.1 and using clang 13.1.6 compiler:

```
% cat code.cpp
#include <vector>
const int SIZE = 43691;
std::vector<int> v[SIZE];

int main() {
  return 0;
}
% cc -std=c++17 code.cpp -o code -lc++
% ./code
```

Also fails with gcc-12.2.0:

```
% g++-12 -std=c++17 code.cpp -o code
/var/tmp/ccEnyMCk.s:449:29: error: unexpected token in '.section' directive
        .section .data.rel.ro.local
                                   ^
```

So it seems to be a `gcc` issue on M1 issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gcc-12 problem on Darwin Aarch64 targets. It shall not emit such sections like `.section .data.rel.ro.local`. Section names on macOS shall start with `__`, eg.: `.section __DATA,...`
See [Mach-O](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/CodeFootprint/Articles/MachOOverview.html) reference.